# How do I get the attribute action from closest form in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to solve an issue I have where I need to grab the `action="/uri/"` from the parent form when a user clicks the submit button. If I use `$(form).live('submit')` it only works half the time. So I am using `$('input[type=""]').live('click')` instead. However as you can see in the code below, I am trying to grab the action attribute and it does not recognize it, or rather I can't seem to grab the `.attr('action')` off of it.

```
<script>
var get_pages_load_options = { 
    target:        '#content',
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
    success:       showResponse
};
$('input[type="submit"]').live('click',function(event){
    var url = $(this).closest("form").attr('action');
    var named = $(this).closest("form").attr('id')
    console.debug(url+"/"+named);
    $("#"+named).ajaxForm(get_pages_load_options);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {ajaxtype: "side"},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#sidebar_menu").html(data);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
</script>
```

The html that I am trying to use looks like this (removed PHP for readability sake):

```
<tr>
    <td class="bold" colspan="2">
        <form id='defcon_form' name='defcon_form' action='/cityhall/' method='post'>
            <div class="left">
                Realm Hoarding 
                <select name='defcon_rate'>
                    <option value='0'>None</option>
                    <option value='10'>Low</option>
                    <option value='20'>Medium</option>
                    <option value='30'>High</option>
                    <option value='50'>Critical</option>
                </select><br />
                <font size='-4'>(Stashes Gold/Turn, Decreases Defense)</font>
            </div><div class="right">
                <input type='submit' name='defcon' value='Update Hoarding!' />
            </div>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I know the HTML isn't the best and I will need to go back and revise it a bit.

Comment: you cannot nest `form` elements

Comment: Are you sure that your submit button is inside of a form tag and that the form tag has an action attribute? `console.log($(this).closest("form").get())`

Comment: Changed the wording, to make sure that it is more clear.

Comment: Where are the form tags located? I see you are using a table. Are the form tags inside the table, or outside of it.

Comment: I removed `event.preventDefault(); return false;` And the form plugin started working again. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. `<tr></tr>` elements can only contain `<td></td>` and `<th></th>` elements. Invalid html will have inconsistent results across browsers or possibly not work at all in any browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/tr

Wrap the form around the entire table instead of each tr, and give each tr a data-key to contain the id of the given tr. With that, you can catch any submit that gets to the form, get the id of the current row by using `$(this).closest('tr').data("key")`, then post the values from the inputs within said tr.

Comment: Hmmmm how can I fix the HTML so that the form goes across the two `<td>` elements?

Comment: I would use a single form around the entire table and handle the form data on a per-row basis.

Comment: Okay, the table can actually have that `<tr>` split off because it is not critical information or even make the `<td>` with a `colspan="2"`. Let me try that and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: It pulls the action now, but I have to try and see if I can get the Form Plugin to run.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.closest` try using `.parent` as in:

```
var url = $(this).parent().attr('action');
```

Comment: if `.closest()` didn't work, `.parent()` definitely won't work.

Comment: The only problem is that the parent is a `<td>` tag, lol. I already  tried it though.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).parents("form").attr('action');
    console.debug(url);
    $(this).ajaxForm(get_pages_load_options);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {ajaxtype: "side"},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#sidebar_menu").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```